# Have to destroy and re-deploy pipeline stack after replacing Github token

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I uses CDK to create and deploy pipeline(with AWS CodePipeline https://aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/), and today Source stage stopped working, complaining about insufficient permission, which turns out to be that the Github token is expired. Error:

[image]

> "Could not access the GitHub repository: "pandaWebsite". The access token might be invalid or has been revoked. Edit the pipeline to reconnect with GitHub."

So I re-genereate the Github token, and updated it in AWS Secrets Manager. And click "Retry" button in pipeline, and it still failed. Eventually I have to run `cdk destroy` to destroy the pipeline, and run `cdk deploy` to re-deploy the pipeline, and then it works.

My question is, why I have to destroy and re-deploy the pipeline? I was expecting that once I updated the token in Secrets Manager, it should just work.

#### More context

AWS Secrets Manager is where I stored the Github token, and my CDK code fetch from it. See code here:

```js
 // Add Source stage to fetch code from GitHub repository.
  private addSourceStage(
    pipeline: codepipeline.Pipeline,
    sourceCode: codepipeline.Artifact
  ) {
    pipeline.addStage({
      stageName: "Source",
      actions: [
        new codepipeline_actions.GitHubSourceAction({
          actionName: "Checkout",
          owner: "yangliu",
          repo: "pandaWebsite",
          branch: "main",
          // read the value from Secrets Manager
          oauthToken: CDK.SecretValue.secretsManager(
            "github-token"
          ),
          output: sourceCode,
          trigger: codepipeline_actions.GitHubTrigger.WEBHOOK,
        }),
      ],
    });
  }
```

Comment: My guess is that you simply restarted the stage, not the whole pipeline. I'd have tried a new pipeline execution before the stack destruction. By restarting the stage only, you may (not sure of this) have used the same values that the previous run (including the old token value).

Comment: @zessx : yes, I only tried restart the stage, not the whole pipeline. I think you are correct that restart the stage may only retry with the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself.
The reason this occurs is because when you use CDK to generate the pipeline it pulls the secret and embeds the token into the pipeline action.

Updating the secret independently wont matter because CDK has already deployed the pipeline and the pipeline was simply using what it was originally given.

This explains why destroying the pipeline and recreating it fixes this issue, because a "fresh" secret has been embedded at the time of cdk deploy for pipeline creation.